# mxnet throws no errors when binding the wrong context

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, mxnet

I wish to see exactly which cpu or gpu my mxnet program is running, so I add a `print self._ctx` at the source code of [executor.py](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/python/mxnet/executor.py). 
Then I bind the executor with gup(10), but no error was thrown since I only have one gpu in my computer. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate a context object for a non-existent GPU.  But if you try to use it, it will throw an exception.